# Java: naming conventions for thread safety?

Tags: java, multithreading, design-patterns, naming-conventions

Imagine I have this class:

```
class Notifier {
    public Listener listener;

    public void notify() {
        if (listener != null) {
            listener.stuffHappens();
        }
    }
}
```

This code is incorrect in the case `listener` can be changed from another thread.  Let's fix it:

```
class Notifier {
    public volatile Listener listener;

    public void notify() {
        Listener l = listener;
        if (l != null) {
            l.stuffHappens();
        }
    }
}
```

The code is correct now, but the `notify()` method looks weird in isolation.  Imagine a larger class with a mix of volatile and regular fields used in the same method and you'll get the picture.

My first impulse is to name the variable `volatileListener`---assuming it's private and there's a `setListener()` of course, but I imagine a "hungarian notation is evil" knee-jerk reaction from many people.

So, are there established practices/conventions?  Or maybe there are some patterns allowing to systematically avoid such situations.  What do you do when writing heavily multi-threaded code?

Comment: What's the point of saving the `volatile listener` into a local variable in the second example?

Comment: @Matt - It avoids the problem where the variable gets changed halfway through the method ... it's a common technique for observer notification, but normally the listener/listener list is not exposed as public.

Comment: @Matt: So that he can check it for `null` and then call its `stuffHappens` method, without getting into a race condition with other code that can assign to `listener`. Otherwise, it may well be that `listener` is `!null` as of the check, but `null` as of the call.

Comment: While not directly related to the question, but I'm not sure that the second example is correct. Using `volatile` with reference types can lead to a lot of troubles, think about DCL for example: http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-02-2001/jw-0209-double.html The problem is that even the reference gets updated correctly, it may point to a half-initialized object because its fields aren't volatile.

Comment: @Sergey: a volatile var is a synchronization primitive in Java. According to Java memory model, a write to a volatile var in thread 1 happens-before a corresponding read in thread 2. This implies that any writes in thread 1 that happen-before writing to volatile also happen-before the read in thread 2. I.e. if you fully initialize your object _before_ assigning it to a volatile, you're guaranteed to get a reference to an initialized object in another thread.

Comment: Volatile only synchronizes access to the variable itself, not to the object it points to. So even if you initialize an object and then put a reference to it into a volatile variable, you could still see the actual effects of the initialization happening much later in another thread. Unless the fields of the object being initialized are all volatile too. The page 4 of the article I gave the link to explains that pretty well.

Answer (score 4):

> What do you do when writing heavily multi-threaded code?

Separate the code that cares about threading from the code that doesn't.

Having a class responsible for notifications is a good start, but your comment about "change[ing] listener from another thread" is disturbing -- and making your `listener` variable public is even more disturbing. Make it private, and add methods to `Notifier` to control changes.

*And don't add code to `Notifier` that does anything other than notify listeners*.

Comment: @Anon: my example was obviously simplified.  If there were `setListener()` it wouldn't change anything in my question.  Then, if there's `setListener()` then it's probably called more than once, and if there's `notify()` then it's probably called from a different thread---cannot see anything 'disturbing' here.

Comment: @Anon: here's another example.  There's `Image` which is empty.  There's `ImageLoader` which fetches image in a separate thread.  Image receives updates from the loader.  It also serves render requests from another thread.  It also notifies anybody who cares about the updates.  How would you separate the `Image`?

Comment: @SnakE - regarding `Image`: I'd question whether an image has any value until it's loaded. Assuming no, then I'd treat `Image` as an immutable object that will be passed to listeners once loaded, but not before. The `ImageLoader` can run in its own thread, and it would use a properly-synchronized and encapsulated `Notifier` to alert listeners once the image is loaded. In this breakdown, no class but `Notifier` needs to care about threading (with the caveat that `ImageLoader` might need a thread-safe work queue)

Comment: @SnakE - actually, that's an over-simplified solution. In the real world, you create a concurrency *architecture* for your application, and specific classes that cross thread barriers. For example, in a Swing app you know that GUI updates have to happen from the event dispatch thread. So your `Notifier` is smart enough to cross that boundary. And rather than create `ImageLoader` as a service (as I'm assuming in my former comment), you might create it as a simple `Runnable` that's passed to an `ExecutorService`. Perhaps with a reference to a thread-safe image cache.

Comment: @SnakE - regardless, my key point remains: the `ImageLoader` *does not do notification itself*.

Comment: @Anon: a) in my case, `Image` can be displayed even if only partially loaded, like in a browser; b) assuming `ImageLoader`, `Image`, and `DocumentView` are all not thread-safe, and `DocumentView` can only be manipulated from a UI thread, what do I do? Make `Image` accept not `Listener` but `interface Notifier`, and pass it `DocumentViewNotifier` instance which knows how to post events to the `DocumentView` queue?

Comment: @Snake - Why not send a stream of `PartialImage` events from `ImageLoader` to `DocumentView`? This keeps `Image` immutable, and keeps the `ImageLoader` and `DocumentView` thread-unaware. And it keeps "intelligence" where it belongs: only the `ImageLoader` knows that it has loaded enough to make a valid partial image.

Comment: At this point, we're going deep into design (and perhaps it would have helped if you'd put real-world examples in your original question). All I can say is that your life will be easier if you keep thread-aware and thread-unaware code separate, and do as much as you can with immutable objects.

Answer (score 2):

This is not a naming convention, but in [Java Concurrency in Practice](http://www.javaconcurrencyinpractice.com/) the authors suggest using [annotations](http://jcip.net/annotations/doc/net/jcip/annotations/package-summary.html) to describe thread safety policies.

I would highly recommend this book to anyone writing multi-threaded code in Java.

Comment: And here is the tool that does static code analysis to catch concurrency bugs http://www.checkthread.org/index.html

Answer (score 2):

Brian Goetz suggested in his book "Java Concurrency in Practice" the usage of Annotations to mark fields an classes as thread-safe or not.

http://www.javaconcurrencyinpractice.com/annotations/doc/net/jcip/annotations/package-summary.html

(Nerveless Anon is right, separate thread safe and not thread safe code.)